# What will be the upper bound of $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

> > Consider the sets $A_i \subset \{1,2, \cdots, n \}, 1 \leq i \leq k$ such that $A_i \cap A_j \neq \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$. Give an upper bound of $k$.

I have found sets $A_i = \{j : 1 \leq j \leq i \}$. Then clearly $A_i \cap A_j \neq \emptyset$. In fact for $i \neq j$ with $i<j$ we have $A_i \subset A_j$ $\implies A_i \cap A_j = A_i \neq \emptyset$. Since $A_i$'s are $n$ in numbers. So we have $k \geq n$. Can we do much better than that? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187211/maximum-intersecting-subsets).

Comment: What you have now is a LOWER bound: $k \geq n$.  A trivial UPPER bound would be $2^{n}$, since there are $2^n$ subsets of $\{1, \dots, n\}$.  (A subset either contains 1 or doesn't.  A subset either contains 2 or doesn't. etc.)